# How to return promises in a loop without exiting the loop?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I've got this admittedly very messy Firebase function.

```
exports.getAverage = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}/days/{day}')
    .onUpdate((snapshot, context) => {
        let averages = {};
        let temp = [];
        let dayRefDoc = admin.firestore().collection(`users/${context.params.userId}/days`)
        return dayRefDoc.get().then(inner => {
            console.log(inner.docs);
            for (doc of inner.docs) {
                console.log(doc);
                return doc.ref.collection('session').get().then(session => {
                    session.docs.forEach(doc => temp.push(parseInt(doc.data().duration)))
                })
            }
        }).then(() => {
            console.log(temp);
            averages["sessionTime"] = (temp.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; }, 0)) / temp.length;
            return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(context.params.userId).get().then(inner => {
                return inner.ref.update({ averageSessionTime: averages.sessionTime })
            })
        })
    })
```

The idea here is that each `user` in my database has a subcollection of `days` and each day has a subcollection called `session`. I want to go through each `session` document across all days and count up a variable called `duration`, then get the average of all durations across all sessions across all days.

Getting the average isn't difficult. I'm struggling with promises right now. Particularly, getting the function to iterate over every `days` subcollection on a particular user. My solution right now works for the first document it iterates over, but doesn't fetch the next, presumably because `doc.ref.collection('session').get().then()` is a promise of its own, and I'm running a return on this promise which causes it to break out of the `for (doc of inner.docs)` loop.

Am I correct in thinking that this is the issue? I feel like using a loop to create these promises is a bad idea anyway, so what would be the intended practice for doing something like this?

Answer (score 0):

I thing you're on the right track. My first idea:

```
let docs = [];
for (doc of inner.docs) {
            console.log(doc);
            docs.append( doc.ref.collection('session').get() )
}
Promise.all(docs).then( values => {...} );
```

So you would collect all promises in a list, wait for all promises to be resolved and the do whatever you like on the results.